# Google Mobile Ads SDK Depreccated

Tags: android, admob, ads

I tried to put Ads in my Android mobile app. When I went to download the **[Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#download)** it shows it is deprecated...

If it is deprecated then what jar I should download... I am using Android Studio for development...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Google Mobile Ads is now offered through Google Play services"

To install Google play service : https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Notice that : "The Google Play services library does support publisher IDs from the legacy AdMob console, and is compatible with existing mediation adapters."